# I need some help with this question

Tags: think-different

The question is like this:

```
8  | 5 |  21
35 | 32|  12 
32 | 28|  31 
?? | 0 |  28
```

I tried  to find a relationship between the columns but I couldn't find one.

If you know please tell me.

Comment: Can the off-topic flagger provide any reasoning behind this? OP is asking for a solution to a number puzzle in a game for iphone/android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **10**

---

For each row the sum of the last column's digits are equal to the first column number subtracted by the 2nd columns number.

If, for example we had `x y ab`. Note that ab represents the digits, not numbers, in the first row a would be 2 and b would be 1 since the third column number is 21.

The formula is `a+b = x-y`.

Substituting the first row we have:

`2+1 = 8-5`, `3 = 3`.

Substituting the last row values we would get:

`2+8 = ?? - 0`

Rearranging for `??` we have:

`?? = 10`